# Cannot reach local plugin observer using user_loggedin event

Tags: php, moodle

I'm just learning how to do a local plugin on Moodle :

I'm trying to execute an action while the user log in

Here is my folder :

- local

  - firsttimeconnect

    - classes

      - observer.php
    - db

      - events.php
    - version.php

content of **observer.php** :

```php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

class local_firsttimeconnect_on_login_observer
{
    public static function local_firsttimeconnect_on_login(core\event\base $event, $user) {
        var_dump($user);
        die();
    }
}
```

content of **events.php** :

```php
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname' => '\core\event\user_loggedin',
        'callback' => 'local_firsttimeconnect_on_login_observer::local_firsttimeconnect_on_login',
    ),
);
```

I keep getting this error while logging in (which means the event is kinda triggering at the good time):

**Can not execute event observer 'local_firsttimeconnect_on_login_observer::local_firsttimeconnect_on_login'**

So far I've seen that if I call directly the function `local_firsttimeconnect_on_login` on an external file, it's working perfectly so I dont think the issue is here.

I've tried several way to call my method by specifing namespace and/or path even from root but I still cant reach it, all I've managed to do is either to get this error or reach normal dashboard without stopping on die or doing anything

Comment: Have you purge cache and increment version number of the plugin to register the observer during upgrade process ?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed still having the same error message

Comment: i had a similar problem : Does your plugin have a table? If so, you should not just change the version number via version.php but through db/upgrade.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, I wasn't calling the file with the method in the events :

```
$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname' => '\core\event\user_loggedin',
        'callback' => 'local_firsttimeconnect_on_login_observer::local_firsttimeconnect_on_login',
        'includefile' => 'local/firstimeconnect/locallib.php',

    ),
);
```

Comment: seems like this was it but I wonder why PSR rules have not picked up a namespace
Unless that just Totara thing and Moodle is still old school about it.